# Is there any way to split a huge EDMX?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, ef-database-first

I have an Entity Framework 5, DB-First project, with over 400 tables in the schema.  When we make changes to the schema, it's difficult to view the diffs because the EDMX file is so huge.

So a long shot: is there any way to split the edmx file into multiple files, in the same way that you can have partial classes split across multiple files?

Alternatively, is there some way of splitting the EDMX into multiple diagrams, e.g. different conceptual sections of the schema could be defined in different diagrams - though we would need to share some tables between different diagrams then, in order to have all associations properly defined?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
In Visual Studio 2013, you can create different diagrams.
So... the model classes are all part of the same context, but you can move them to different diagrams.

I'm not sure about having the same class in several diagrams... I'm inclined to say that is not possible.

Check this article to see how it works: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj519700.aspx

Comment: +1 for pointing out the ability to have multiple diagrams; that is useful.  But it doesn't help the source control diffs - those are still huge.  I was hoping for some way to split the EDMX itself... like if you could have one EDMX per diagram, that would be perfect.

Comment: Yes... the file itself is just one (actually two, but not one per diagram). For me this advance was huge at the time I discovered them, and we don't work in paralell in the model so we didn't find issues yet.